# How to display notification count badge on app icon in Oreo?

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I'm getting the notification in `Oreo` version. But i need to show count badge on app icon. I'm not able to display the count badge. Please Help

Thanks in Advance :)

Function for getting the notification

```
public void sendOnChannel1(View v){
            String title = editTextTitle.getText().toString();
            String messagge = editTextMessage.getText().toString();
            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,CHANNEL_1_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_one)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(messagge)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                    .setNumber(3)

                    .setBadgeIconType(NotificationCompat.BADGE_ICON_SMALL)
                    .build();


            notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
    }
```

And this function is for create notification channel

```
 private void createNotificationChannels() {
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
                try{
                    NotificationChannel channel1=new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_1_ID, "Channel 1", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
                    channel1.setDescription("This is Channel 1");
                    channel1.setShowBadge(true);
                    channel1.canShowBadge();
                    NotificationManager manager=getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
                    manager.createNotificationChannel(channel1);
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
```

I want to display count badge on app icon

Comment: Hi,Did you find answer for this?